# Meaning of Sifra D'Hafkona

Tags: names, shemot-exodus

Online i found another name for the book of Exodus/Shemot, Sifra D'Hafkona. 
What does it mean and how to translate this in English and Hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

It probably comes from the Aramaic root מפק or נפק which means to take out, so it means the same thing as Exodus.